# How to write the regex to check if a string contains any of the keywords

Tags: java, regex

I need to check each line of my html files whether it has js/css/jpg file included. If so, I am going to do something more on these lines.
For example:

```
<img src="logo.jpg" />
<script src="head.js"></script> //double quotes
<script src='head.js'></script> //single quote
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

These are all the cases matche the checking rule.
But `<script src="head.json"></script>` will not be matched because it doesn't exactly match the keyword "js".

I am writing a Java application to scan the html source and want to design a regular expression for the checking. Basically I think it needs to check whether each line contains .js"/', .css"/' and .jpg"/'.

In future there might be more keywords to add. How to write the regular expression elegantly?

Comment: as allways, regex isn´t the proper tool to analyze html content

Comment: When you need to **parse**, then use a *parser*, not regular expressions as dirty non-robust workaround.

Comment: in addition: what have you tried so far?

Comment: antlr4 would be useful for parsing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an answer to the question :
How to match `js` but not `json`?

You can use word boundaries :

```
\b(js|jpg|css)\b # or
\.(js|jpg|css)\b
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/m2OARR/1) here.

If you want to parse HTML with Java, use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Yes, I am trying the same.